# Calculating heritability: pedigree information with family variation

Tags: matrix, genetics

currently I am aiming to calculate heritability, for which I would have to estimate additive genetic variance (the inverse of the relatedness matrix) for a first step. This is done with the following code (from Suppl 1 here https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0197720):

```
# first get the pedigree from the data
pedigree<-Mermaids[,c("id","dam","sire")]
# inserts any missing individuals into the pedigree
missing<-unique(Mermaids$id[which(!Mermaids$id%in%pedigree[,1])])
if(length(missing)>0){
pedigree<-insertPed(pedigree, missing)
}
# Orders the pedigree so that parents come before their offspring
pedigree<-orderPed(pedigree)
# Gets the inverse of the relatedness matrix
Ainv<-inverseA(pedigree)$Ainv
```

Now, this code, which generates a pedigree matrix, is based on analyzing every individual based on information who the individual's mom and dad were, like so:

```
animal dam sire
66 R187920 NA NA
172 R187921 NA NA
325 R187726 R187920 R187921
411 R187724 R187920 R187921
503 R187723 R187920 R187921
838 R187613 R187920 R187921
932 R187612 R187920 R187921
1030 R187609 R187920 R187921
```

However, in my case I have slightly different data, it is based on collecting data from all members of a family and assuming that offspring are offspring from "individual families" rather than "individual parents". However, I find no way to incorporate family-based variation into this analysis and I hope someone here has a suggestion which functions I could use to analyze my data instead. Here is a small snippet of my data.

```
gen ID  ID-fam  ID-mom  ID-dad
1   ID137   T2  NA  NA
1   ID138   T2  NA  NA
1   ID139   T2  NA  NA
1   ID140   T2  NA  NA
1   ID141   T12 NA  NA
1   ID142   T12 NA  NA
1   ID143   T12 NA  NA
1   ID144   T12 NA  NA
1   ID145   T12 NA  NA
1   ID146   T12 NA  NA
2   ID147   U1  T2  T12
2   ID148   U1  T2  T12
2   ID149   U1  T2  T12
2   ID150   U1  T2  T12
2   ID151   U1  T2  T12
2   ID152   U1  T2  T12
2   ID153   U1  T2  T12
2   ID154   U1  T2  T12
```